# register_deactivation_hook argument -> pass arguments in the selected function

Tags: hooks

I've been looking for minutes how to pass arguments in the `register_deactivation_hook` as follow :

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( new Cpt, 'delete_cpt') ) );

class Cpt
{
    /**
     * Delete a custom post type
     */
    public function delete_cpt($name = 'test') {
        /**
         * delete a single data
         */
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        $GLOBALS['wpdb']->delete( 
            'cpt', 
            array( 
                'name'=>$name 
            ) 
        );
        $GLOBALS['wpdb']->show_errors();
        echo $GLOBALS['wpdb']->last_query;
        echo $name;
        die();
    }
}
```

The function executes but the `$name` var remains empty.
I would like to pass the `$name` directly in `register_deactivation_hook`;

Is it at least possible ? Nothing seen anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a complete function as callback, so you can pass the argument to the method. Example:

```
register_deactivation_hook( 
    __FILE__,
    function() {
        $cpt = new Cpt;
        $cpt->delete_cpt( 'post_type_name' );
    }
);
```

Comment: This will work only with PHP >= 5.3 .

Comment: This fit perfectly. I've been thinking about somthing similar. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static method inside your Cpt class and call that instead with `register_deactivation_hook`; Then you create your object and send it data as usual.

Answer (score -1):

You should replace the `register_deactivation_hook` code line with below code:

`register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Cpt', 'delete_cpt' ) );`

Comment: That wouldn’t solve the problem. Have you _tested_ your suggestion?